# Excel Lookup Data Based on Column Name not Cell Name

Tags: vba, excel, vlookup

I am trying to accomplish a strange task in excel and don't know how to go about it.  I'm using Excel 2007 at work and I know very basic vba.

I want to automate a process where a person takes three spreadsheets and dumps certain data from them into one master sheet.  The three spreadsheets vary every month in their column order, so unfortunately I can't just program vlookups to run and get the data.

I could be wrong, but it seems like Vlookup Match, Index Match Match, etc. wouldn't work either because they are still referencing cells.  **I basically need something that will find a column based on the text in the column, rather than its location, because the location will change, but the text will always be the same.**

I have two ideas but I have no idea if they work and don't really know where to start on implementing them:

1. Convert the three spreadsheets to tables and reference the headings with table syntax (I haven't been able to get this to work)
2. Complex VBA that IDs everything

Can anyone help point me in the right direction to accomplish this task?  Thanks so much for your help.

EDIT EXAMPLE

My main template that I'm trying to dump things into is just going to have the ID#s and empty columns:

```
ID#          AltID#          Deal
1
2
3
4
5
```

And then another spread sheet might have look like this

```
ID#          AltID#          Deal
1            10101           AAAA
2            20202           BBBB
3            30303           CCCC
4            40404           DDDD
5            50505           EEEE
```

I could of course vlookup, but the problem is next month, those columns in the second spreadsheet won't be in the same place, in the same order.  They could be all the way on colum DD or whatever.  So I need a formula that looks them up regardless of the columns location.  Just matching them by the heading text.  I hope that clarifies...

Comment: It would be nice to have some examples. I think `indirect` might help in this situation.

Comment: I will try to add an example with dummy data as soon as possible

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you combine `VLOOKUP` with `MATCH` you can search based on column name, not index. Remember that the `MATCH` function returns the numeric index of the match. Let's assume that your data looks like the below:

```
NAME    DAY1    DAY2    DAY3
Bob     123     345     567
Tim     456     789     998
```

A functioning Vlookup to return the DAY2 column for Tim would look like:

```
=VLOOKUP("Tim", A2:D3,MATCH("DAY2",A1:D1,0),FALSE)
```

A couple of notes. Where I've hard coded in words, you can use cell references.

Comment: I didn't know you could vlookup with a string as your reference, that's cool.  But in need my col_index_num to be a string, not a number.  Or, the number of the column that is a certain string, if that makes sense.

Comment: Perhaps we are misunderstanding each other. Using my mock formula, Excel will pick the col_index_num that corresponds to the string "DAY2". So, if DAY2 is the third column, as it is in my example, the col_index_num will be three. If it moves, the col_index_num will likewise update. Is this not what you needed?

Comment: are you sure it will update?  If I make a macro to do a specific vlookup and write in a # for col_index_num, and then next month the column location is not 3 but 16, how will the macro know to change col_index_num to 16?  I edited my question with an example to hopefully clarify.  Thanks!

Comment: Per my code, your don't enter a specific number for col_index_num. Instead, you use the MATCH function to return the col_index_num for you. Instead of a number, you enter the formula: MATCH("DEAL",A1:D1,0) where the col_index_num would normally go. If deal is the first column, col_index_num would automatically return 1. If it is in column 2 next month, col_index_num would find the text DEAL and return the corresponding column. Does that clear things up?

Comment: Oh, I apologize.  Let me try this and get back to you ASAP!

Comment: Oh man, I think that works!!  Much simpler than I thought it would be.  I'm going to keep testing this but if all goes well, this will be marked as correct and upvoted.  Thanks so much!!

Comment: No problem! Let us know if you have additional problems.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69326/discussion-between-msim-and-user3561813).

Answer (score 0):

Here is one idea:

- get the index of the column `ID#` in Sheet2 `MATCH("ID#",Sheet2!$1:$1,0)`
- convert to a character: `CHAR(MATCH("ID#",Sheet2!$1:$1,0)+64)`
- get the column range: 
    `INDIRECT(
       CONCATENATE("Sheet2!",
                   CHAR(MATCH("ID#",Sheet2!$1:$1,0)+64),":",
                   CHAR(MATCH("ID#",Sheet2!$1:$1,0)+64)))`
- similarly for column `AltID#`:
  `INDIRECT(
       CONCATENATE("Sheet2!",
                   CHAR(MATCH("AltID#",Sheet2!$1:$1,0)+64),":",
                   CHAR(MATCH("AltID#",Sheet2!$1:$1,0)+64)))`

with range of `ID#` and `AltID#`, we can do the match+index:

```
=INDEX(
   INDIRECT(
     CONCATENATE("Sheet2!",
                 CHAR(MATCH("AltID#",Sheet2!$1:$1,0)+64),":",
                 CHAR(MATCH("AltID#",Sheet2!$1:$1,0)+64))),
   MATCH(A2,INDIRECT(
              CONCATENATE("Sheet2!",
                          CHAR(MATCH("ID#",Sheet2!$1:$1,0)+64),":",
                          CHAR(MATCH("ID#",Sheet2!$1:$1,0)+64))),0))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an idea to consider:


Give a name to cell ID# e.g "dataJanuary" and use this named-cell as reference using an OFFSET function then you can explore it with vlookup or index-match function or other method.


Next month even if the ID# column is moved to other column or row, it will always reference to the same data since the cell is already named with "dataJanuary".

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).